# Application Center installers web-app shows error when installing mobile-client

Tags: ios, mobile, installation, mobilefirst-appcenter

This is with reference to the Application Center. Getting this error when attempting to download the mobile-client uploaded to the Application Center when tried from within a simulator:

"*Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.*"

and the following error when attempting the same step from a browser running on a device:

"*Cannot install applications because the certificate for  is not valid.*"

In both cases, the login to the mobile-web-app at https:///applicationcenter/installers.html was successful. I am assuming that this means that the certificate was valid. [Note the Application center has a web-server reverse proxy in front of it.]

Additionally, in both cases, when the mobile-client is side-loaded from Xcode, these errors are not seen. In such cases, once the mobile-client is installed and running, the target app is downloadable and runnable from the application center store.

Any pointers that explains why the installers mobile-web-app is throwing these errors?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the version of MFP being used is 8.0

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mobile browser to access the installers.html or inst.html page.

Comment: Yes.. this is implicit in my original post - that is the only way to download installers (mobile-client) from the application center. The errors reported occur upon trying to download the mobile-client once the installers.html page (and the associated web-app) are running inside the mobile device's browser.